# How to affine decipher text in bash?

Tags: bash, encryption

My encryption code.

```
#!/bin/bash

affine_encrypt() {
    text="$1"
    a="$2"
    b="$3"

    affine_transformation() {
        char="$1"
        a="$2"
        b="$3"
        echo "$(( (a * ( ( $(printf "%d" "'$char") - $(printf "%d" "'A") ) + b ) % 26 ) + $(printf "%d" "'A") ))"
    }

    encrypted_text=""
    for (( i=0; i<${#text}; i++ )); do
        c="${text:$i:1}"
        if [[ "$c" =~ [A-Za-z] ]]; then
            encrypted_text+="$(printf \\$(printf '%03o' "$(affine_transformation "$c" "$a" "$b")"))"
        else
            encrypted_text+="$c"
        fi
    done

    echo "$encrypted_text"
}

# # Example usage:
# text="Hello, World!"
# a=5
# b=8
# encrypted_text=$(affine_encrypt "$text" "$a" "$b")
# echo "Original text: $text"
```

My decipher code not bringing back the original text.

```
mod_inverse() {
    a="$1"
    m="$2"
    m0="$m"
    x0="0"
    x1="1"

    while [ "$a" -gt 1 ]; do
        q=$((a / m))
        t="$m"
        m=$((a % m))
        a="$t"
        t="$x0"
        x0="$x1"
        x1="$((t - q * x1))"
    done

    if [ "$x0" -lt 0 ]; then
        x0="$((x0 + m0))"
    fi

    echo "$x0"
}
affine_decrypt() {
    ciphertext="$1"
    a="$2"
    b="$3"
    alphabet_size="26"

    decrypted_text=""

    a_inverse=$(mod_inverse "$a" "$alphabet_size")

    for char in $(echo "$ciphertext" | sed 's/./& /g'); do
        if [[ "$char" =~ [a-zA-Z] ]]; then
            ascii_value=$(printf '%d' "'$char")
            decrypted_value="$(( a_inverse * (ascii_value - b) % alphabet_size))"

            # Handle negative values
            if [ "$decrypted_value" -lt 0 ]; then
                decrypted_value="$((decrypted_value + alphabet_size))"
            fi

            # Convert back to ASCII character and append to the decrypted text
            decrypted_text+=$(printf "\\$(printf '%03o' "$((decrypted_value + 65))")")
        else
            decrypted_text+="$char"
        fi
    done

    echo "$decrypted_text"
}

# Provide a and b as command-line arguments
a="4"
b="8"

# Given ciphertext
ciphertext="IUWWI, QIUWQ!"

# Decrypt using provided a and b
decrypted_text=$(affine_decrypt "$ciphertext" "$a" "$b")

echo "Decrypted text: $decrypted_text"
```

Please suggest how to fix that?

Decipher code I shared, not bringing back the original text passed to encryption. Need help on that

I tried passing "Hello, World!" with 4 and 8 as values to it. encryption happening. But decryption, not bringing this text back.

```
echo $(affine_encrypt "Hello, World!" "4" "8")
IUWWI, QIUWQ!

bash decryption.sh
d.sh: line 12: a / m: division by 0 (error token is "m")
Decrypted text: AAAAA,AAAAA!
```

Comment: What have you done to debug your code? What happens if e.g. `b` is set to zero? What do you get instead of the correct plaintext? The main thing I see that is wrong is that you keep to the ASCII values instead of converting those into a zero based index.

Comment: added output above, can you see once. Same output in decrypt even if b is 0 or 8

Comment: So to perform calculations modulus n means that the elements should be in the group 0..n-1. So e.g. the letter `A` should have value `0` not `0x41`. The easiest way to do this is to subtract the ASCII value of `A` from the ASCII of the letter you are encrypting / decrypting. And doing it the other way around after performing the calculation. This of course screams for using two functions (`charToIndex` or something).